# Will -std=c++11 compiler flag be default at some point?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-flags

As in title. Will it be default or to use C++11 features we will always have to add `-std=c++11`?

Right now, because of this option, C++11 still feels like some extra, non-standard thing.

To specify compiler, `-std=c++11` flag is used by clang, g++ and even ICC.

Comment: I think future.stackexchange.com is where they hold the time machine.

Comment: A good question but for the GCC mailing lists :)

Comment: It might help to specify the compiler.

Comment: @legends2k Also, clang and g++ do have that flag, but might have different policies regarding defaults.

Comment: Yes, clang mimics g++ perhaps for a business reason otherwise even that might have had a different flag

Comment: @legends2k Not always. A classic example is the `-fdiagnostics-color` and `-fcolor-diagnostics` flag.

Comment: @zmbq well, I was not asking when, but if it will become default. It could be that for conceptual reasons the flag would always need to be set.

Answer (score 5):

With g++, use `-dumpspecs` to generate a `specs` file.
Use `-print-search-dirs` and first line is where to place `specs` file.
Add the `-std=c++11` option appropriate place in `specs` file, on the line following `*cc1plus:`.

Comment: What do you put in the specs file? I keep getting `fatal error: specs file malformed after 2409 characters`. I tied a few things like: `std=c++11` and `-std=c++11` and `c++11` to no avail.

Comment: just `-std=c++11` works with MinGW g++ in Windows. don't know in Unix-land, but probably the same. the only real difference is with paths, they shouldn't be quoted and backslashes must be escaped with backslashes.

Comment: Thnx, works now. No idea why it didn't work for me before I must have mistyped something.

Comment: Maybe you added extra blank line or something. Blank lines are significant in specs files. And for that matter in network protocols.